# JUnit testing Java failure

Tags: java, junit

Below are my codes, MyQueue interface and JUnit tester. My code seems to be alright but the test kept failing though there is no error. Can anyone please help me figure it out? Thanks :)

MyQueue interface:

```
import java.util.*;

public interface MyQueue {
    void enqueue(int in);

    int dequeue() throws NoSuchElementException;  // throw exception if isEmpty() is true

    int noItems(); // returns the number of items in the array

    boolean isEmpty();  // true if queue is empty
```

}

JUnit tester code:

```
import java.util.*;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class CircularArrayQueueTest extends TestCase
{

    private void checkSize( int length, MyQueue queue )
    {
        assertEquals( "Queue has wrong number of elements", length,
                queue.noItems() );
        if( length == 0 )
            assertTrue( "Queue should be empty", queue.isEmpty() );
        else
            assertTrue( "Queue should not be empty", !queue.isEmpty() );
    }

    public void testSimple()
    {
        MyQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        checkSize( 0, queue );
        queue.enqueue( 3 );
        checkSize( 1, queue );
        try
        {
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", 3, queue.dequeue() );
        } catch( NoSuchElementException e )
        {
            throw e;
        }
        checkSize( 0, queue );
    }

    public void testMultiInput()
    {
        MyQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        for( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
        {
            int r = ( int )Math.round( Math.random() );
            checkSize( 0, queue );
            queue.enqueue( r );
            checkSize( 1, queue );
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", r, queue.dequeue() );
        }

    }

    public void testManyEnqueueDequeue()
    {
        CircularArrayQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        int cnt = 0;
        for( int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i )
        {
            if( Math.random() > 0.5 )
            {
                queue.enqueue( i );
                cnt++;
            } else
            {
                if( !queue.isEmpty() )
                {
                    queue.dequeue();
                    cnt--;
                }
            }
            assertEquals( "Correct number of items", cnt, queue.noItems() );
        }
    }

    public void testLargeQueue()
    {
        MyQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        int[] r = new int[ 1000 ];
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            r[ i ] = ( int )Math.round( Math.random() );
            checkSize( i, queue );
            queue.enqueue( r[ i ] );
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", r[ i ],
                    queue.dequeue() );
            checkSize( r.length - i - 1, queue );
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            r[ i ] = ( int )Math.round( Math.random() );
            checkSize( i, queue );
            queue.enqueue( r[ i ] );
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", r[ i ],
                    queue.dequeue() );
            checkSize( r.length - i - 1, queue );
        }
    }

    public void testThrows()
    {
        MyQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        int[] r = new int[ 1000 ];
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            r[ i ] = ( int )Math.round( Math.random() );
            checkSize( i, queue );
            queue.enqueue( r[ i ] );
        }
        for( int i = 0; i < r.length; ++i )
        {
            assertEquals( "Dequeue returns wrong element", r[ i ],
                    queue.dequeue() );
            checkSize( r.length - i - 1, queue );
        }
        boolean throwsCorrectly = false;
        try
        {
            queue.dequeue();
        } catch( NoSuchElementException e )
        {
            throwsCorrectly = true;
        }
        assertTrue( "Throws when dequeuing empty queue", throwsCorrectly );
    }


    public void testResize()
    {
        CircularArrayQueue queue = new CircularArrayQueue();
        assertTrue( "Initial capacity too large", queue.getCapacityLeft() <= 1024 );
        for( int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
        {
            queue.enqueue( i );
        }
        int currentCapacity = queue.getCapacityLeft();
        while( currentCapacity > 0 )
        {
            queue.enqueue( 9 );
            currentCapacity--;
            assertEquals( "Array size should not change", currentCapacity,
                    queue.getCapacityLeft() );
        }
        assertTrue( "Should have reached capacity", queue.getCapacityLeft() == 0 );
        queue.enqueue( 42 );
        assertTrue( "Should have resized array",
                currentCapacity < queue.getCapacityLeft() );
        currentCapacity = queue.getCapacityLeft();
        for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
        {
            queue.enqueue( i );
            currentCapacity--;
            assertEquals( "Resizing too often (inefficient)", currentCapacity,
                    queue.getCapacityLeft() );
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my own written code:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class CircularArrayQueue implements MyQueue{

    private static final int capacity = 10;//Initial Capacity
    private Integer[] Queue;
    private final int count; // capacity
    private int head = 0;
    private int tail = 0;

    //  Creates an empty queue using the capacity.
    public CircularArrayQueue(){
         count = capacity;
         Queue = new Integer[count];
    }

    //  Adds the specified element to the tail of the queue, expanding
    //  the capacity of the queue array if necessary.
    public void enqueue(int in) {
        if(isFull()){
            expandCapacity();
        }
           Queue[tail] = in;
           tail = (tail + 1) % Queue.length;
    }


    //  Creates a new array to store the contents of the queue with
    //  twice the capacity of the old one.
    public void expandCapacity() {
        Integer[] larger = ((Integer[]) (new Integer[Queue.length * 2]));

        for (int scan=0; scan < Queue.length; scan++) {
            larger[scan] = Queue[head];
            head = (head+1) % Queue.length;
        }
        head = 0;
        tail = Queue.length - 1;
        Queue = larger;
    }

    //  Removes the element at the head of the queue and returns a
    //  reference to it. Throws an EmptyCollectionException if the
    //  queue is empty.
    public int dequeue() throws NoSuchElementException {
        int item; 
        if(isEmpty()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }else{
            item = Queue[head];
            Queue[head] = null;
            head = (head + 1);
        }
       return item;
    }

    //  Returns the number of elements currently in this queue.
    public int noItems() {
        if(tail > head)
            return tail - head;
        return count - head + tail;
    }

    //  Returns true if this queue is empty and false otherwise.
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (tail == head) ? true : false;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        int diff = tail - head; 
        if(diff == -1 || diff == (count -1))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int getCapacityLeft() {
        if(isFull()){
            return 0;
        }else{
            return count-noItems();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Failing with what error message?

Comment: For reproduction, `interface MyQueue` is missing.

Comment: @ChristianHujer code updated with MyQueue interface thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating the queue, `head` is 0, `tail` is 0 and `count` is `capacity`, and `capacity` is 10.

`noItems()` in that case returns `count - head + tail` which is `10 - 0 + 0`, so for an empty `queue` in Test `testSimple()`, `noItems()` returns `10` instead of the expected `0`.

Inspect the error messages that you are getting, they're telling you precisely that. For example, you get:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Queue has wrong number of elements expected:<0> but was:<10>
at ...
```

That you write unit tests is a good thing. There is some potential for further improving your techniques about that:

- Write the tests first, actually do the Red-Green-Refactor-Cycle of TDD following Uncle Bob's Three Laws of Test-Driven Development.
- Use JUnit 4 instead of JUnit 3.
- Follow the Single-Assert-Rule. Each test case should contain only one logical assertion.
- Use BDD. Clearly specify "given arrangement, when action, then assertion".
- Write smaller methods. `testLargeQueue()` is way too long.
- DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself. Remove redundancy. For example, in `testLargeQueue()`, there is a lot of redundancy.
- `try { foo(); } catch (NoSuchElementException e) { throw e; }` is the same thing as just `foo();`. Why so complicated... (in `testSimple()`)
- The convention for `assert` messages actually is to describe the expected (correct) behavior, not the actual (wrong) behavior. Also, convention is to no longer use these messages - the name of the test case should say it already.
- In your specific case, you might actually want to go for TestNG instead of JUnit. For testing objects where test cases depend on states which can be established by preceding test cases, TestNG is far superior over JUnit. I usually default to JUnit, but in this case I really recommend to use TestNG instead.